# std::hash algorithm and size

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, hash, stdhash

I'm using C++11 and the std::hash algorithm. 
I was wondering, what actual hash implementation is used? 
I would assume MD5 or SHA, but I can't dig any info from the internets.

Also, I'd like to know the actual returned bit-width of the hash, as I have to store it in MySQL.

Finally, is it preferable to use std::hash, over say some other library such as crypto++ ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The algorithm chosen for `std::hash` is solely implementation dependant. Probably neither MD5 or SHA are used since they would be performance killers for its purpose.

Most implementation will be much more trivial than the above mentioned since there is no cryptographic requirement for `std::hash` while MD5 and SHA have been developed for cryptographic purposes.

The [requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) of `std::hash` are much less strict:

1. Accepts a single parameter of type `Key`.
2. Returns a value of type `size_t` that represents the hash value of the parameter.
3. Does not throw exceptions when called.
4. For two parameters `k1` and `k2` that are equal, `std::hash<Key>()(k1) == std::hash<Key>()(k2)`.
5. For two different parameters `k1` and `k2` that are not equal, the probability that `std::hash<Key>()(k1) == std::hash<Key>()(k2)` should be very small, approaching `1.0/std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`.

Comment: Now you got me worried about collisions. I'm extensively using std::hash for creating unique identifiers. For GCC then, would it be safe to assume that std::hash offers a trade between performance and non-cryptographic security (uniqueness of hash)?

Comment: You have to understand that the uniqueness provided by `std::hash` nothing has to do with cryptographic security. Its implementation is mostly used with associative unordered containers like map. The implementation doesn't care about cryptographic, it cares about efficiency when used to manage hash tables. If you need cryptographic security then you should really point toward an external library meant to be used for that purpose.

Comment: Oh and by the way, both MD5 and SHA-0/1/256/512 have been proven to be not so safe in cryptographic contexts so you shouldn't trust them either: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Cryptographic_hash_algorithms

Comment: Forget I even mentioned cryptography. All I care is about uniqueness for associated objects. That's why I'm worried, if the algorithm is implementation-dependant, how can I rest quiet concerning collisions of hashes for different objects/types used in std::hash?

Comment: What are you talking about? Collisions are expected to happen with any hash table!

Comment: No hash function is perfectly collision immune. That's obvious if you see that the codomain of an hash function has a cardinality which is usually orders of magnitude lesser that its domain. Given that you must trust the implementation about the fact that collision are not frequent. But you have to take care of the possibility of having a collision in any case and with any hash function.

Comment: "I'm extensively using std::hash for creating unique identifiers." I'm taking this as: "I want a library to generate [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)s". That's not `std::hash`.

Comment: @peppe, no that's not what I mean. I am mapping objects, based on their hash, generated by certain members. Albeit I understand that no hash function is collision free, I am asking if this is a *somewhat* safe thing to do using std::hash

Comment: @Alex, @peppe.  I agree, you want a UID type, such as a standards-defined UUID, implemented in several libaries, including [`boost::uuid`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/uuid/).

Comment: @Alex, UUIDs implement SHA and MD5 hashes of string-data, as well as completely pseudo-random generated, if you're interested.  Read-up on [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Comment: If you want to peek at the implementation (remember that it can change **at any time**), libstdc++ hash maps 1) integrals into themselves 2) pointers into themselves 3) MurmurHash for float, double, `std::string`s, and as the "default implementation", see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/functional_hash.h;hb=HEAD) and [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/hash_bytes.cc;hb=HEAD).

Comment: @peppe It's not the same a collision because two values havgin same hash, and a collision because two values end up in the same bucket. The second solely depends on the `bucket_count`. Two different hashes could end up in the same bucket because of the modular arithmetic `hash % bucket_count`. Any type `T` with `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(std::size_t)` has a 0 probability of hash collision, so it maps to itself.

Comment: @peppe Gcc for instance always uses a `bucket_count` that is a prime number. Since prime numbers are not uniformely distributed, the probability of two values having a same module from a same prime number is always lower than to any other number (or that's what I guess). Also, in case of rehashing, two values that are in a same bucket (equals or multiple of some prime) are guaranteed to be in different buckets after reashing.